# Pass file name to perl from R

Tags: r, perl

I want to pass file name to perl from R. For example, this system command from R to execute perl works well

```
system("perl file.pl name.txt")
```

name.txt is already existing in the R working directory. Now,

```
a<-"name.txt"
```

how to pass this to perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly I think this may work:

```
a <- "name.txt"
system(sprintf("perl file.pl %s", a))
```

Comment: This **wont work** if the filename contains spaces (or other specials) and its a **gaping security hole** if this code gets run on a server and the client can specify the file name (google: "Bobby Tables"). Use `shQuote(a)` to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Tyler's method works, but there is also this way:

```
a <- "name.txt"
system(paste("perl file.pl", a))
```

Depending on the situation, one may be more intuitive over the other.